# Vue - wrap text selection with span and make style two-way binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am writing an application which allow users to highlight text by different colors while reading.

I use [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to achieve this function.However I am having issues with the two-way binding.If the user change the color, the highlighted text will not update simultaneously.

Anyone can help? http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/424087/

To clearify my question, the effect I want is that when user changed the color, all the text highlighted before will also update.

Reproduction:

1. default color `#ccc`
2. highlight some text (it's gray)
3. choose another color, for example `#ff0000`(now if you highlight some new text it will be red, however I want the text highlighted before to be red, but it's still gray because the span is created via `createElement`,not bound to vue's data)

html:

```html
<div id="app">
  <label v-for="color in colors">
    <input type="radio" v-model="currentColor" :value="color">
    {{color}}
  </label>
  <h4>Select Text To Highlight</h4>
  <p id="text" @mouseup="highlight">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum ducimus veniam esse, nam rerum cumque repellat maiores! Explicabo laudantium, magni dignissimos impedit labore, dolores deserunt aspernatur eos quo, vero consequatur.
  </p>
</div>
```

js:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentColor:'#ccc',
    colors: ["#ccc","#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"],
    selectedRange: null
  },
  methods: {
     getSelectedText() {
      if (window.getSelection) {
        let sel = window.getSelection()
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
          this.selectedRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
        return window.getSelection().toString()
      } else if (document.selection) {
        this.selectedRange = document.selection.createRange()
        return document.selection.createRange().text
      }
      return ''
    },
    surroundSelection(color) {
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.className = 'highlight'
      span.style.fontWeight = "bold"
      span.style.color = color
      span.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log('click');
      });
      if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection()
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
          var range = this.selectedRange.cloneRange()
          range.surroundContents(span)
          sel.removeAllRanges()
          sel.addRange(range)
        }
      }
    },
    highlight(){
        let text = this.getSelectedText();
      if (this.selectedRange && text) {
          this.surroundSelection(this.currentColor)
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: for me it updates simultaneously

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim select #ccc , highlight text by #ccc, then choose another color for example #ff0000, I want the highlight text goes red

Comment: i have the same behavior when i highlight using gray the text will be gray, and when i choose another color the selection will be with new chosen color

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I have edited my question to clearify my situation

Comment: ok i understood your use case

Answer (score 1):

Adding a watcher for currentColor could solve this since now color is setted to span.style.color only when selection changes.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    currentColor:'#ccc',
    currentSpan: null,
    colors: ["#ccc","#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"],
    selectedRange: null
  },
  watch: {
    currentColor: function (newColor, oldColor) {
        if (!this.currentSpan) {
          return;
        }

        this.currentSpan.style.color = newColor;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...
    surrountSelection: function (color) {
      ...
      return span;
    },
    highlight: function () {
      if (this.selectedRange && text) {
        this.currentSpan = this.surroundText(this.currentColor);
      } else if (this.currentSpan) {
        this.currentSpan = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```